# Them wolves or their wolves?

Tags: pronouns

I just came across on lyrics of Eminem's "survival" which confused me. Here is piece of song which confused me.

> Throw me to them wolves and close the gate up on me.

I thought that correct phrase is their wolves instead them wolves. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here, "them wolves" is another, somewhat low-brow, way of saying "the wolves".

Comment: In standard English, it actually means *"those wolves"*. [See dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/them) (2nd definition).